# What kind of problems will an administrator at data center will be facing?

Tags: administration, server-administration

Suppose there is a guy maintaining a Server connecting 50-60 systems.What are the general problems that the administrator will be facing in maintaining those 50-60 systems.

Comment: Why the 'computer-science' tag?

Answer (score 0):

- Broken application software.
- Security vulnerabilities in applications
- Kernel upgrades
- Broken hardware
- Resource starvation (memory, disk, DB space, CPU, network bandwidth, ...)
- Data intrusions
- Power issues
- Accidental hardware damage (someone tripping in the data centre, soaking teh DB server in coffee...)
- Configuration skew

There are probably more things that I have simply not mentioned, but I'd say that 90% of the "server-related" issues would fall in one or more of the categories above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for a data center administrator is not going to be all-encompassing since data center administrators kind of do it all. The answer to this question could vary just as much as the hardware in the data center itself.

If the data center is already built, then you're looking at your standard
- system administrator tasks (for all of the different kinds of systems)
- networking tasks
- power and cooling issues
- procurement and general maintenance

If the data center isn't built, you need to understand the client-base and then you'll understand what needs to be done. For example, if it's just your standard windows environment, it could be as simple as your standard windows cluster with your vmware and all the works. If you're maintaining a hospital then chances are you're going to be dealing with a variety of proprietary softwares on generic hardware.

Building is much different from maintenance but once it's built, it may give you a good chance to learn a variety of systems and sometimes the complicated networking that goes behind keeping things moving and secure.